# vba datediff function written inside string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have a text box, and when the user enters a value into this text box I am filtering a form. The user enters a "7" inside the text box and a form opens with all records updated in the past 7 days. In order to do this I am using

```
docmd.openform "myform", , , stringfilter
```

stringfilter is a string I created where I am trying to use the datediff function. The name of my field that has the last edited date is called [timestamp]. So I thought this would work but for some reason it does not:

```
stringfilter = "datediff( " & "d," & "#timestamp#," & "now" & ") < " & mytextbox.value
```

I expect the output of this string to be the following, but i don't believe it is:

```
datediff("d",timestamp,now) < 7
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are using the filter string in SQL query but you can try this:

```
Dim iD As Integer
iD = Val(mytextbox.value)
'Any err trapping goes here if userinput is valid before opening your form

stringFilter = "Datediff('d','" & VBA.Format$([DateField], "dd/mm/yyyy") & "','" & VBA.Format$(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "') < " & iD
```

in above method you are converting both dates to one format for more accurate result. you can forgive #tags within Datediff command. Having said that Datediff command can recognize different date-formats

**Alternative1**:
just add another column to your query as:

```
DateDiff("d",[updated_date],Now()) as lastUpdatedInDays
```

and you can open the form with where condition like

```
docmd.OpenForm formname,acNormal,,"[lastUpdatedInDays]<" & id
```

Comment: I may be wrong as I don't use access. I guess you are trying this? `"DATEDIFF(""D"",'" & format([DateField],"YYYY-MM-DD") & "','" & format(now,"YYYY-MM-DD") & "')"` Notice the `""D""`

Comment: ahhhh SO much easier. I was unable to figure out the VBA string mess, but adding a new "lastupdated" field to the query in sql was easy. then i just used vba to docmd.openform "myform", , , "lastupdated" & "<myvalue" worked like a charm, thanks for the idea! why didnt i think of that....

Answer (score 0):

Theres an easier way to get the date 7 days ago.

```
Date() - 7
```

Each day equals 1 in dates.

Comment: The user specifies the number of days, that's why i'm using the textbox value, but thanks for trying!

Comment: I was just showing you the basic function of adding / subtracting days. In your case, it would have been date() - mytextbox.value